# Python grab a whole column from CSV file ignoring comma with double quotes

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python.
I want to grab a whole column from a *.csv file.
in order to do so, I saw that my best way is to convert my csv to 2-dim. array using:

```
   > import numpy as np
   > csv=np.genfromtxt(file_name.csv, delimeter=",")
```

and than for example if I want to grab the 8-th column just to write:

> column8=csv[:,7]

my problem is that I have fields, in double quotes, with a comma in them, so I have a ValueError:

> ValueError: Some errors were detected !
>
> ```
> Line #6 (got 16 columns instead of 15)
>
> Line #21 (got 16 columns instead of 15)
>
> Line #45 (got 18 columns instead of 15)
>
> etc.
> ```

so all I want is, if for example this is my csv:

> a,b,c,d
>
> f,g,h,"i,j"
>
> k,l,m,"n,o,p"

so if for example I want to grab the 4-th column I want the answer to be:

> d
>
> i,j
>
> n,o,p

any ideas anyone??

thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in `csv` module takes care of this nicely with the default settings. So this should just work:

```
import csv
with open("file_name.csv", "r", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    column8 = [row[7] for row in reader]
```

This is a slight variation on the [first example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) in the [module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which contains additional useful information.

Answer (score 0):

pandas is very good for reading from csv files.

try to use:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv", delimeter=",") # header=None)
```

after this, to access a column

```
df['colname'] # or df[col_ind] if you set header=None
```

Comment: hi, but how I ignore commas in double quotes, and how I grab a whole column?

Comment: It ignores commas in double quotes by default. You can use param quotechar to specify another behavior.

Comment: and,  set `header=None` to not use first row as the columns names

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas package will solve your problem. As pandas has a wide variety of methods from which we can read different file formats.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
    print df[column4]
```

Comment: hi, but what if I want to grab column by its number and not by its name? (i.e. df[:,3] and not df[column3]?

Comment: You could use df.ix[:,3]

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to taleinat's solution, but if you know the header_name and want to return a list.

```
import csv

with open(FILENAME, "rb") as MEDIA:
headers = []
columns = []
required_header = "name"
csv_file = csv.reader(MEDIA, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=DELIMITER)
for row in csv_file:
    headers = row[:]
    break
position = headers.index(required_header)
[columns.append(row[position]) for row in csv_file]
return columns
```